# Get tasks for queue using CloudTasksClient

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to stop tasks that are queued and I need to get tasks for a queue.

I can use this but this will list all tasks for that client and i want just tasks for the query

```
const client = new CloudTasksClient();
const [tasks] = await client.listTasks({ parent });
```

Is there a better way to do this

Comment: You can't stop task. You can only delete them. So you can either delete the taskQueue, or  list the task and delete them one by one. The advantage of the 2 options is that you can also save elsewhere the tasks in the queue to replay them later if you want. More here: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v2.projects.locations.queues.tasks

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes but how would i get all the tasks for a queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @guillaumeblaquiere's comment, here are the links to sample codes to [manage queues and tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/deleting-appengine-queues-and-tasks):

- [Deleting a task from a queue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/generated/v2/cloud_tasks.delete_task.js)
- [Purging all tasks from a queue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/generated/v2/cloud_tasks.purge_queue.js)
- [Pausing queues](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/generated/v2/cloud_tasks.pause_queue.js)
- [Deleting queues](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/blob/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/generated/v2/cloud_tasks.delete_queue.js)

Here are some of the references that you may find helpful:

- [Cloud Tasks Queues REST API](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest#rest-resource:-v2.projects.locations.queues.tasks)
- [Google Cloud Tasks sample codes for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/tree/main/packages/google-cloud-tasks/samples/generated/v2)
- [Class v2.CloudTasksClient (3.1.2)](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/tasks/latest/tasks/v2.cloudtasksclient)

I would suggest [filing for feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if you want this option so that Google engineers could take a look at this. This doesn't have an ETA but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.

Comment: I need to do this things from code i create queues for each user and they have their own tasks runing so if he abandons those tasks i need to stop / delete those tasks